# Can't get Dijit layout to work in Javascript API (BorderContainer/ContentPane)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

**EDIT:** Well this is probably a big part of the issue, it appears my parser is not working. How do I fix that?

[image]

I'm using the Javascript API 3.23. For whatever reason, when I create a BorderContainer and put content panes inside, the regions aren't respected, instead they just stack up on each other. I see a lot of old posts use notation like "dijit.layout.BorderContainer" instead of "dijit/layout/BorderContainer" - I am wondering if this is part of my problem? The dojo documentation I read uses slashes instead of periods, I figured the periods are a thing of the past but maybe not. One other thing I noticed was instead of region: 'left' or region: 'right', dojo documentation now states it is region: 'leading' or region: 'trailing' so I am pretty confused...

HTML:

```
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'" id="content">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
        <div id="toolbar-pane">
            //stuff here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leading" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'leading'">left</div>
    <div id="mapp" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">center</div>
    <div id="trailing" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'trailing'">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
#leading {
width: 500px;
border: 5px solid red;
}
#trailing {
width: 200px;
border: 5px solid blue;
}
#content {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

JS require statement:

```
require([
"esri/map",
"esri/request",
"esri/arcgis/utils",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
"esri/tasks/Geoprocessor",
"esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
"esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
"esri/graphic",
"esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
"esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
"esri/Color",
"esri/InfoTemplate",
"esri/tasks/query",
"esri/tasks/QueryTask",
"esri/dijit/Legend",
"esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
"dijit/layout/ContentPane",
"dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",
"dijit/layout/AccordionPane",
"dojo/parser",
"dojo/query",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/on",
"dojox/widget/Standby",
"dojo/domReady!"
],
function (
Map,
esriRequest,
arcgisUtils,
FeatureLayer,
Geoprocessor,
SimpleLineSymbol,
SimpleFillSymbol,
Graphic,
UniqueValueRenderer,
SimpleRenderer,
Color,
InfoTemplate,
Query,
QueryTask,
Legend,
parser,
PopupTemplate,
query,
dom,
domConstruct,
on,
Standby
) {
  parser.parse();
```

Yields this (don't worry about there being no map, I can make the map show up in the "center" region if I want):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reorganize my require statement and put dijit/layout/... at the end after the parser and such. I also had to make sure in my CSS that the `#content` id was set to the same as html and body, essentially this:

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/request",
    "esri/arcgis/utils",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/tasks/Geoprocessor",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
    "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
    "esri/Color",
    "esri/InfoTemplate",
    "esri/tasks/query",
    "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
    "esri/dijit/Legend",
    "esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
    "dojo/query",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojox/widget/Standby",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
],
  function(
    Map,
    esriRequest,
    arcgisUtils,
    FeatureLayer,
    Geoprocessor,
    SimpleLineSymbol,
    SimpleFillSymbol,
    Graphic,
    UniqueValueRenderer,
    SimpleRenderer,
    Color,
    InfoTemplate,
    Query,
    QueryTask,
    Legend,
    PopupTemplate,
    query,
    dom,
    domConstruct,
    on,
    Standby,
    parser
  ) {
      parser.parse();
```

and the CSS:

```
html, body, #content {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```